# How to get attributes of cell on datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to get attributes from a cell, but I am unable.

My code:

**HTML**

```
<td id="project_quantity_<?=$user->id;?>"    data-type="project"        data-quantity="true" data-id="<?=$user->id;?>"><?=$user->project_quantity; ?></td>
<td id="entailment_quantity_<?=$user->id;?>" data-type="entailment" data-quantity="true" data-id="<?=$user->id;?>"><?=$user->entailment_quantity; ?></td>
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    table.cells('[data-quantity="true"]').every(function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?=base_url("admin/users/getQuantity")?>/"+this.{GET_DATA_ID_ATTRIBUTE},
            data:{type:this.{GET_DATA_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE}},
            type:"post",
            success:function(data)
            {
                cell = table.cell("#"+data.type+"_quantity_"+data.id);
                cell.data(data.ids+"/"+cell.data());
            },
            error: function(x,y,z){console.log(x);}
        });
    });
});
```

The keys `{}` on the code is where I want to get the attributes from the cell.

I hope had been clear on my explanation.

Comment: Do not use this in ajax, since, that is ajax object itself. do a `var obj = $(this)` before ajax, and use `obj.mehtodName()`. In ajax you can use `$obj.data('id');`

Comment: What is `table` in the context? DOM Element, jQ element?

Comment: Hi @Max table is tabe = jQuery("#table").DataTables(); and the cells and every functions are defined here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().every().

Comment: Hi @lolka_bolka the .data("id") method doesn´t work... cells is not a jQuery object. And methodName function is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!!!
I solve it...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    table.cells('[data-quantity="true"]').every(function()
    {
        node = jQuery(this.node());
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?=base_url("admin/users/getQuantity")?>/"+node.data("id"),
            data:{type:node.data("type")},
            type:"post",
            success:function(data){
                cell = table.cell("#"+data.type+"_quantity_"+data.id);
                cell.data(data.ids+"/"+cell.data());
            },
            error: function(x,y,z){console.log(x);}
        });
    });
});
```

Where the important line is this one:

```
node = jQuery(this.node());
```

And after I can make things like this:

```
data:{type:node.data("type")}
```

Thank you everyone.

**Documentation:**

[datatables: .every() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every())

[datatables: .cell().node() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().node())

[datatables: .cell().data() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data())

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataType = $(this).data('type');
... // your AJAX stuff directly below.
```

That should give you the value set to data-type= on your dom objects.

Comment: Thanks @b-d-b but it doesn´t work, I think that it would work if I was using: jQuery('[data-quantity="true"]').each(function(){$(this).data('type');});

Comment: That would work with each, but since you're using every, try something like this:

    `this.dataset.type`

Comment: ummm No @b-d-b... it doesn´t work :( it isn´t a jQuery object, it is a datatable cell, with its own api...

Comment: Since no one here really knows what object you have, I would recommend setting one of the cells to `window.cell` (e.g. `window.cell = this`), then opening up the console and working with the object directly there.  From there you can just access `window.cell` directly and see what methods/data is contained in it from the console.